# AWS SES Email Receiving not available in Frankfurt

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, aws-regions

[AWS SES dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnTmS.png)

I've set up AWS SES for Frankfurt and I can send emails just fine, but it seems that the "Email Receiving" section is disabled + all the documentation shows that only Dublin can use SES.

It seems weird to be able to send emails from Frankfurt, but not be able to receive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are rignt, Only three regions support email receiving .

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US West (Oregon)
- Europe (Ireland)

reference: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-receive-email

Comment: Should I set receiving in Ireland and sending in Frankfurt? Tbh, it seems unnecessary cumbersome

Comment: I think thats the only way. You can ask AWS support for advice

Comment: What you do is to verify the domain in Ireland instead. I don't think the same domain can be verified in multiple regions.

Comment: @AlecuMarianAlexandru how did you proceed?

Comment: @Besnik I moved to Ireland unfortunately